# Dropdown in navbar is not working in rails 6

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6

Dropdown menu by using bootstrap 4 in navbar is not working. i am using rails6.
gemfile and application.js is given below. Bootstrap and jquery is properly installed.

this is my gemfile:-

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.3.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
```

application.js file:-

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

//= require jquery
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Please share relevant code and efforts related to issue and mention the issue in more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow jquery behaves special in rails 6. In order to work correct, I had to add it through yarn (which is a different version of jquery).

Enter this in your terminal (application directory):

```
yarn add jquery popper.js
```

Then go to your environment.js and make it look like this:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require("webpack")
environment.plugins.append("Provide", new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
$: 'jquery',
jQuery: 'jquery',
Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))
module.exports = environment
```

Then go to your application.js and import bootstrap:

```
import "bootstrap"
```

This should work